# Accessing test PostgreSQL database from python

Tags: python, psycopg2

I can't seem to correctly connect and pull from a test postgreSQL database in python.  I installed PostgreSQL using Homebrew.  Here's how I have been accessing the database table and value from the terminal:

```
xxx-macbook:~ xxx$ psql
psql (9.4.0)
Type "help" for help.

xxx=# \dn
 List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner  
--------+---------
 public | xxx
(1 row)

xxx=# \connect postgres
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "xxx".
postgres=# SELECT * from test.test;
  coltest  
-----------
 It works!
(1 row)
```

But when trying to access it from python, using the code below, it doesn't work.  Any suggestions?

```
########################################################################################
# Importing variables from PostgreSQL database via SQL commands

db_conn = psycopg2.connect(database='postgres',
                           user='xxx')

cursor = db_conn.cursor()

#querying the database
result = cursor.execute("""
Select * From test.test
""")

print "Result: ", result
>>> Result: None
```

It should say: Result: It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the results.

From the docs:

> The **[`execute()`-]method returns None**. If a query was executed, the returned values can be retrieved using **`fetch*()`** methods.

Example:

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

For reference:

- http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#execute
- http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#fetch

Note that (unlike `psql`) `psycopg2` wraps anything in transactions. So if you intend to issue persistent changes to the database (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, ...) you need to commit them explicitly. Otherwise changes will be rolled back automatically when the connection object is destroyed. Read more on that topic here:

- http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html
- http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#transactions-control